# C++: No match for operator for the same types of operand

Tags: c++, vector, types, iterator, operators

I have a vector of a map of int and float
`std::vector<std::map<int, float>> datad;`

And I want to iterate over the maps in vector and inside over pairs in map

```
for (std::vector<std::map<int, float>>::iterator currentMap = datad.begin(); currentMap < datad.end(); ++currentMap)
{ 
 for (std::map<int, float>::iterator it = currentMap->begin(); it < currentMap->end(); ++it)
     {/*some code here*/}
}
```

But in the second loop `g++` compiler gives an error:

```
no match for ‘operator<’ (operand types are ‘std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const int, float> >’ and ‘std::map<int, float>::iterator’ {aka ‘std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const int, float> >’})
```

But isn't it looks like the types

```
std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const int, float>>
std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const int, float>>
```

are the same?

Yes, I see that compiler says the `currentMap->end()` have the type `std::map<int, float>::iterator` but...it is aka `_Rb_tree_iterator`...

maybe

```
static_cast<std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const int, float>>>(currentMap->end())
```

What is the easiest way to continue using iterators and fix the problem?

PS. static_cast don't work, it gives

```
no match for ‘operator<’ (operand types are ‘std::map<int, float>::iterator’ {aka ‘std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const int, float> >’} and ‘std::map<int, float>::iterator’ {aka ‘std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const int, float> >’})
```

PSS. I've also tried `auto` but it also doesn't work (the same error as the first one)

Comment: Use `!=` instead of `<`. Not all iterators are order-comparable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::map`'s iterators are bidirectional iterators, not random access iterators. Therefore they do not provide relational comparison operators. You can only equality-compare them.

So replace `<` with `!=`, which is the standard way of writing iterator loops. Or even better, replace the loop with a range-for loop:

```
for (auto& currentMap : datad)
{ 
    for (auto& el : currentMap)
    {
        /* Use el here as reference to the (pair) element of the map. */
    }
}
```